# A modular arithmetic question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am a beginner in modular mathematics. I can't figure out is 
$$a^b \bmod m = (a \bmod m)^{(b \bmod  m)} \bmod  m$$

If this is the case, can you please give me some hint how to prove this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with explicit $a,b,m$?

Comment: Yes i have, it seems to be true for smaller numbers to me, but i can't prove this

Comment: Actually i am implementing a program in which i am using the same concept and getting wrong answer which makes me wonder if this formula is correct or not.

Comment: Try $5^3 \bmod{3}$ and $5^0 \bmod{3}$ (where $3 \equiv 0 \bmod{3}$).

Comment: You seem to be thinking of mod as an operation, not a relation.

Comment: for m=10,there is repetation in every 4succesion of b .i.e. if b=1 and b=5 answer of a^b for mod 10 is same. how can i find the no of seccesion for m=10^9+7.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is in effect, "if $a\equiv a_1\pmod m$
and $b\equiv b_1\pmod m$ then is $a^b\equiv a_1^{b_1}\pmod m$?"

The answer is no: $2\equiv 5\pmod 3$, but $2^2\not\equiv 5^5\pmod 3$.

Answer (score 0):

The real relation is this:
$$a^b\mod m\equiv(a\bmod m)^{b\bmod\varphi(m)}\mod m$$
as  results from *Euler's theorem* ($\varphi$ is the totient function).

*Example* :
by *Fermat's theorem*, if $p$ is prime, $\;a^b\equiv a^{b\bmod p-1}\mod p$.

Comment: I tried this but it didnt worked for my program.  in my case m=10^9+7 which is prime,

Comment: so i computed b mod(m-1) power to a instead of b power to a but it didnt worked.

Comment: @Anukulgaurav: What do you mean with ‘It didn't work’?  Did it produce a wrong output?

Comment: yes i used it in a programmming and it produced wrong answer.

Comment: I think it's a programming problem. Normally you have to use the *fast exponentiation algorithm*, reducing mod. $m$ at each step. The best would be to test your program on a computation you can mimick by hand until it yields a correct result.